# $(X-P) - (N\cdot(X-P))N = (I - NN^T)(X-P)$ how to prove this?

Tags: matrices, transpose

$(X-P) - (N\cdot(X-P))N = (I - NN^T)(X-P)$

I see a text about Orthogonal projection onto a plane, and this formula I cann't understand, can someone please explain to me, or give me some guide information, I have learn algebra some long time ago, which I forget most of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
(X-P) - (N\cdot(X-P))N&=(X-P)-N^T(X-P)N \qquad\text{note that $N^T(X-P)$ is a scalar} \\
&=(X-P)-NN^T(X-P)\\
&=(I-NN^T)(X-P)
\end{align}

Comment: why $(N\cdot V)N = N^TVN$ ?

Comment: @LiuHao for vectors $A,B$ $$ A\cdot B= A^TB$$